# CSS Notification box

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, notifications

I have been following the below guide on how to setup this CSS Notifcation Box but it doesn't appear to work. Is there anyone that could try it out themselves and help troubleshoot with me if you have the same problem?

https://www.c5insight.com/Resources/Blog/tabid/148/entryid/653/how-you-make-sharepoint-announcements-grab-attention-easily-using-csr.aspx

Comment: Can you include where you're stuck/how far you are? Are you getting any effects, or nothing at all? Also, do you have scripts enabled for your site collection?

Comment: I am using this in SharePoint Online. I have got to the point or linking the announcements web part to the "homepage_message_override.js" file but the style is not being applied.